# UITableView Strange Scrolling Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

I am stuck in quite strange issue. My UITableView struck strangely. I have custom cell in my TableView. Here is the video reference. It will explain the issue quite well
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CwHzzQgnCXCZZQEKiiWAzOpvIJ9LNvJ1/view?usp=sharing

```
//Here is my TableView Delegates
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.recepientChatModel?.sectionKeys.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let key = self.recepientChatModel?.sectionKeys[section]
        return (self.recepientChatModel?.sectionMessages[key!]?.count)!
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    if let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SectionHeaderTableViewCell") as? SectionHeaderTableViewCell{
        let key = self.recepientChatModel!.sectionKeys[section]
        
        headerCell.configure(sectionDate: key)
        return headerCell.contentView
    }
    return UIView()
}
```

// Here is my code of cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "replycell") as! ReplyCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        let key = self.recepientChatModel!.sectionKeys[indexPath.section]
        let item = (self.recepientChatModel!.sectionMessages[key]?[indexPath.row])
        
        if(item!.messageText.contains("\(API.baseURL.baseU)/FANTEXT/attachment") || item!.messageText.contains(".giphy.com/media/") || item!.messageText.contains("https://api.twilio.com") || item!.messageText.contains(API.baseURL.baseU))
        {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
            tapRecongnizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
            cell.sent_image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.sent_image.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
            cell.receive_image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.receive_image.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecongnizer1)
        }
        
        cell.configure(msg: item!)
        
     //   cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
```

//While recepientChatModel is the Model containing data from API

// And here is my configure function

```
func configure(msg:MessageData) {
        receive_image.image = UIImage(named: "")
        sent_image.image = UIImage(named: "")
        lbl_receiveMsg.text = ""
        lbl_sentMsg.text = ""
        
        if msg.messageType == "InboundMsg" {
            var textMessage = ""
            if msg.messageText.contains("jpg") || msg.messageText.contains("jpeg") || msg.messageText.contains("png") || msg.messageText.contains("gif")
            {
                imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 250
                self.receive_image.isHidden = false
                self.receive_image.backgroundColor = .clear
                btn_playReceive.isHidden = true
                self.receive_image.image = UIImage(named: "img_placeholder")
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0 ){
                    self.activityInd.center = CGPoint(x: self.receive_image.frame.size.width  / 2  ,
                                                      y: self.receive_image.frame.size.height / 2  )
                    
                    self.activityInd.style = .whiteLarge
                    self.activityInd.color = UIColor.darkGray
                    self.receive_image.addSubview(self.activityInd)
                    self.activityInd.startAnimating()
                    self.receive_image.kf.setImage(with: URL( string: msg.messageText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!), placeholder: UIImage(named: "img_placeholder"), options: [.transition(.fade(0.7))], progressBlock: nil){ (img, err, cache, url) in
                        self.activityInd.stopAnimating()
                    }
                }
                
                textMessage = msg.addtlMessageText
            } else if msg.messageText.contains("mp4") || msg.messageText.contains("mov") {
                self.receive_image.image = UIImage(named: "VideoPlaceholder")
                self.receive_image.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                self.btn_playReceive.isHidden = false
                self.receive_image.isHidden = false
                urlString = msg.messageText
                textMessage = msg.addtlMessageText
                imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 250
            } else {
                receive_image.isHidden = true
                self.btn_playReceive.isHidden = true
                textMessage = msg.messageText
                imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
            }
            
            sentMessageView.isHidden = true
            receiveMessageView.isHidden = false
            lbl_receiveMsg.isHidden = false
            lbl_receiveMsg.text = textMessage.emojiUnescapedString
            
            lbl_receiveMsg.text = textMessage.emojiUnescapedString
            lbl_receiveMsg.numberOfLines = 0
            lbl_receiveMsg.enabledTypes = [.mention, .hashtag, .url , customType]
            lbl_receiveMsg.customColor[customType] = UIColor.blue
            lbl_receiveMsg.text = textMessage.emojiUnescapedString
            lbl_receiveMsg.textColor = .black
            lbl_receiveMsg.handleHashtagTap { hashtag in
            }
            
            lbl_receiveMsg.handleURLTap { (url) in
                let myURl = url
                var stringUrl:String = myURl.absoluteString
                stringUrl = stringUrl.lowercased()
                if stringUrl.contains("http") || stringUrl.contains("Http") || stringUrl.contains("Https") || stringUrl.contains("https"){
                    
                    guard let url = URL(string: "\(url)") else { return }
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                }else{
                    guard let url = URL(string: "http://\(url)") else { return }
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                }
                
            }
            lbl_receiveMsg.handleCustomTap(for: customType) { element in
                if element.contains("http") || element.contains("https") || element.contains("Http") || element.contains("Https")||element.contains("HTTPS")||element.contains("HTTP") {
                    guard let url = URL(string: element) else { return }
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                } else if element.contains(".com") && element.contains("http".lowercased()) == false && element.contains("https".lowercased()) == false && element.contains("WWW".lowercased()) == false {
                    guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.\(element)") else { return }
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                } else if element.contains("www".lowercased()) && element.contains("http".lowercased()) == false && element.contains("https".lowercased()) == false {
                    guard let url = URL(string: "http:\(element)") else { return }
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                } else {
                    if(self.canOpenURL("https://"+element)) {
                        guard let url = URL(string: "http:\(element)") else { return }
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            lbl_receiveTime.isHidden = false
            
            let timeStamp = self.convertUTCDateIntoLocalDate( dateStr: msg.createdDateTime)
            let components: [String] = timeStamp.components(separatedBy: " ")
            lbl_receiveTime.text = "\(components[1])".timeConversion12()
        } else {
            if (msg.messageText.contains("\(API.baseURL.baseU)/FANTEXT/attachment"))
            {
                constraint_imageHeight.constant = 250
                sent_image.isHidden = false
                sent_image.image = UIImage(named: "img_placeholder")
                let components: [String] = (msg.messageText.components(separatedBy: "https"))
                if components.count == 1
                {
                    urlString = components[0]
                }
                else
                {
                    urlString = "https\(components[1])"
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0 ){
                    if msg.messageText.contains(".mov"){
                        self.sent_image.image = UIImage(named: "VideoPlaceholder")
                        self.sent_image.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                        self.platBtn.isHidden = false
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.platBtn.isHidden = true
                        self.sent_image.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                        self.activityInd.center = CGPoint(x: self.sent_image.frame.size.width  / 2  ,y: self.sent_image.frame.size.height / 2  )
                        self.activityInd.style = .whiteLarge
                        self.activityInd.color = UIColor.darkGray
                        self.sent_image.addSubview(self.activityInd)
                        self.activityInd.startAnimating()
                        self.sent_image.isHidden = false
                        self.sent_image.kf.setImage(with: URL( string: self.urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!), placeholder: UIImage(named: "img_placeholder"), options: [.transition(.fade(0.7))], progressBlock: nil){ (img, err, cache, url) in
                            self.activityInd.stopAnimating()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (msg.messageText.contains(".giphy.com/media/")){
                constraint_imageHeight.constant = 250
                self.sent_image.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                platBtn.isHidden = true
                sent_image.isHidden = false
                sent_image.image = UIImage(named: "img_placeholder")
                let components: [String] = (msg.messageText.components(separatedBy: "https"))
                if components.count == 1{
                    urlString = components[0]
                }else{
                    urlString = "https\(components[1])"
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0 ){
                    
                    self.activityInd.center = CGPoint(x: self.sent_image.frame.size.width  / 2  ,
                                                      y: self.sent_image.frame.size.height / 2 )
                    
                    self.activityInd.style = .whiteLarge
                    self.activityInd.color = UIColor.darkGray
                    self.sent_image.addSubview(self.activityInd)
                    self.activityInd.startAnimating()
                    self.sent_image.kf.setImage(with: URL( string: self.urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!), placeholder: UIImage(named: "img_placeholder"), options: [.transition(.fade(0.7))], progressBlock: nil){ (img, err, cache, url) in
                        self.activityInd.stopAnimating()
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                constraint_imageHeight.constant = 0
                sent_image.isHidden = true
                self.platBtn.isHidden = true
            }
            
            receiveMessageView.isHidden = true
            sentMessageView.isHidden = false
            var stringParts = [String]()
            if msg.messageText.contains("\(API.baseURL.baseU)/FANTEXT/attachment") || msg.messageText.contains(".giphy.com/media/")
            {
                stringParts = msg.messageText.components(separatedBy: "https")
                lbl_sentMsg.text = stringParts[0].emojiUnescapedString
            }
            else
            {
                self.sent_image.backgroundColor = .clear
                lbl_sentMsg.text = msg.messageText.emojiUnescapedString
                lbl_sentMsg.numberOfLines = 0
                lbl_sentMsg.enabledTypes = [.mention, .hashtag, .url, customType]
                lbl_sentMsg.customColor[customType] = UIColor.blue
                lbl_sentMsg.text = msg.messageText.emojiUnescapedString
                lbl_sentMsg.textColor = .black
                lbl_sentMsg.handleHashtagTap { hashtag in
                }
                
                lbl_sentMsg.handleURLTap { (url) in
                    let myURl = url
                    var stringUrl:String = myURl.absoluteString
                    stringUrl = stringUrl.lowercased()
                    if stringUrl.contains("http") || stringUrl.contains("Http") || stringUrl.contains("Https") || stringUrl.contains("https") || stringUrl.contains("HTTP")  || stringUrl.contains("HTTPS") {
                        
                        guard let url = URL(string: "\(url)") else { return }
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                    }
                    else{
                        guard let url = URL(string: "http://\(url)") else { return }
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                    }
                }
                
                lbl_sentMsg.handleCustomTap(for: customType) { element in
                    if element.contains("http") || element.contains("https") || element.contains("Http") || element.contains("Https")||element.contains("HTTPS")||element.contains("HTTP") {
                        guard let url = URL(string: element) else { return }
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                    }else if element.contains(".com") && element.contains("http".lowercased()) == false && element.contains("https".lowercased()) == false && element.contains("WWW".lowercased()) == false{
                        guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.\(element)") else { return }
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                    }else if element.contains("www".lowercased()) && element.contains("http".lowercased()) == false && element.contains("https".lowercased()) == false{
                        guard let url = URL(string: "http://\(element)") else { return }
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                    } else {
                        if(self.canOpenURL("https://"+element)) {
                            guard let url = URL(string: "http:\(element)") else { return }
                            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            lbl_sentTime.isHidden = false
            
            let timeStamp = self.convertUTCDateIntoLocalDate( dateStr: msg.createdDateTime)
            let components: [String] = timeStamp.components(separatedBy: " ")
            lbl_sentTime.text = "\(components[1])".timeConversion12()
        }
    }
```

I know code structure is poor.

I can share code of my whole ViewController and Custom Cell if someone want

Any help or Suggestion will be highly appreciated

Regards,

Comment: Your video explains, well, nothing. You need to provide a good **description** of what's happening, and provide enough code so we can see what you may be doing wrong. Please review [ask] and see [mre].

Comment: @DonMag ok I am sharing my TableView code

Comment: You are doing async code in the view cell but when you are in completion closure you do not check you are updating the correct cell. Cells are being reused, so when scrolling fast enough your closure update a cell which has been reused.

Comment: @PtittXav thanks a lot. Can you suggest a solution please?